# error C2415 at this instruction "MOV Incoming_Packet_Length,DWORD PTR SS:[EBP-14]"

Tags: c++, hook

i am new to c++ and inline asm , searching didn't get me anywhere
im getting error C2415 at

```
MOV Incoming_Packet_Length,DWORD PTR SS:[EBP-14]
MOV Incoming_Packet_Pointer,DWORD PTR SS:[EBP-1C]
```

im hooking this

```
Address   Hex dump          Command    
006D89D0  |> >FF75 EC       PUSH DWORD PTR SS:[EBP-14]
006D89D3  |. |FF75 E4       PUSH DWORD PTR SS:[EBP-1C]
006D89D6  |. |E8 B4C5FFFF   CALL 006D4F8F
```

and the variables i want to get those values at are both static ints

static int Incoming_Packet_Length;
static int Incoming_Packet_Pointer;

thanks

Comment: Have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2ee921w0.aspx) for description of error and possible fix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that C2415 is a "invalid addressing mode". You need to do the move in two steps:

```
MOV      EAX,DWORD PTR SS:[EBP-14]
MOV      Incoming_Packet_Length,EAX
MOV      EAX,DWORD PTR SS:[EBP-1C]
MOV      Incoming_Packet_Pointer,EAX
```

X86 doesn't support moving from memory to memory directly - one side needs to be a register.